# Delete s:element attribute-values in XML(WSDL) file?

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd, wsdl, mule

I want to in my XML (WSDL) file remove s:element between  tag:

```
<wsdl:types>
  <s:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://ws.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/">
  <s:element name="GetWeatherInformation">
  <s:complexType/>
   </s:element>
   <s:element name="GetWeatherInformationResponse">
   <s:complexType>
     <s:sequence>
       <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="GetWeatherInformationResult"    type="tns:ArrayOfWeatherDescription"/>
     </s:sequence>
     </s:complexType>
    </s:element>

        <s:complexType name="ArrayOfWeatherDescription">
        <s:sequence>
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="WeatherDescription"  type="tns:WeatherDescription"/>
        </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
        <s:complexType name="WeatherDescription">
        <s:sequence>
           <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="WeatherID" type="s:short"/>
           <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Description" type="s:string"/>
           <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="PictureURL" type="s:string"/>
       </s:sequence>
      </s:complexType>

       <s:element name="GetCityForecastByZIP">
        <s:complexType>
        <s:sequence>
           <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="ZIP" type="s:string"/>
        </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
        </s:element>
```

Now I want to remove `<s:element name="GetCityForecastByZIP">
            <s:complexType>
            <s:sequence>
               <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="ZIP" type="s:string"/>
            </s:sequence>
            </s:complexType>
            </s:element>`

When I use this structure in my .xslt file `<xsl:template match="s:element[@name = 'GetCityForecastByZIP']" />` after running  I have error in my console , How can I remove it?

I saw this error in my Mule-Console

```
Exception in thread "main" org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentInitException: TransformerConfigurationException: Failed to compile stylesheet. 1 error detected.
at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.init(DefaultMuleApplication.java:220)
at org.mule.module.launcher.application.ApplicationWrapper.init(ApplicationWrapper.java:64)
at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultMuleDeployer.deploy(DefaultMuleDeployer.java:46)
at org.mule.tooling.server.application.ApplicationDeployer.run(ApplicationDeployer.java:56)
at org.mule.tooling.server.application.ApplicationDeployer.main(ApplicationDeployer.java:88)
Caused by: org.mule.api.config.ConfigurationException: Error creating bean with name '_muleNotificationManager': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'serviceName': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException: Failed to compile stylesheet. 1 error detected. (org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException) (org.mule.api.config.ConfigurationException)
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:52)
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.java:78)
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.createMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:80)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.init(DefaultMuleApplication.java:208)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: org.mule.api.config.ConfigurationException: Error creating bean with name '_muleNotificationManager': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'serviceName': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException: Failed to compile stylesheet. 1 error detected. (org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException)
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:52)
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.java:78)
    at org.mule.config.builders.AutoConfigurationBuilder.autoConfigure(AutoConfigurationBuilder.java:101)
    at org.mule.config.builders.AutoConfigurationBuilder.doConfigure(AutoConfigurationBuilder.java:57)
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:46)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException: Error creating bean with name '_muleNotificationManager': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'serviceName': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException: Failed to compile stylesheet. 1 error detected.
    at org.mule.registry.AbstractRegistry.initialise(AbstractRegistry.java:117)
    at org.mule.config.spring.SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.createSpringRegistry(SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.java:116)
    at org.mule.config.spring.SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.doConfigure(SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.java:73)
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:46)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '_muleNotificationManager': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'serviceName': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException: Failed to compile stylesheet. 1 error detected.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:149)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:102)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1442)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:248)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:581)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    at org.mule.config.spring.SpringRegistry.doInitialise(SpringRegistry.java:89)
    at org.mule.registry.AbstractRegistry.initialise(AbstractRegistry.java:109)
    ... 14 more
        Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating                   bean with name 'serviceName': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException: Failed to compile stylesheet. 1 error detected.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1455)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isSingleton(AbstractBeanFactory.java:408)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:319)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeanNamesForType(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154)
    at org.mule.config.spring.ServerNotificationManagerConfigurator.getMergedListeners(ServerNotificationManagerConfigurator.java:83)
    at org.mule.config.spring.ServerNotificationManagerConfigurator.getObject(ServerNotificationManagerConfigurator.java:65)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:142)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException: Failed to compile stylesheet. 1 error detected.
    at org.mule.module.xml.transformer.XsltTransformer.initialise(XsltTransformer.java:142)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.initialise(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:79)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.initialise(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:79)
    at org.mule.construct.AbstractFlowConstruct.initialiseIfInitialisable(AbstractFlowConstruct.java:309)
    at org.mule.construct.AbstractPipeline.doInitialise(AbstractPipeline.java:161)
    at org.mule.construct.AbstractFlowConstruct$1.onTransition(AbstractFlowConstruct.java:111)
    at org.mule.construct.AbstractFlowConstruct$1.onTransition(AbstractFlowConstruct.java:105)
    at org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager.invokePhase(AbstractLifecycleManager.java:141)
    at org.mule.construct.FlowConstructLifecycleManager.fireInitialisePhase(FlowConstructLifecycleManager.java:81)
    at org.mule.construct.AbstractFlowConstruct.initialise(AbstractFlowConstruct.java:104)
    at org.mule.config.spring.factories.AbstractFlowConstructFactoryBean.initialise(AbstractFlowConstructFactoryBean.java:115)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeCustomInitMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1581)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1522)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: Failed to compile stylesheet. 1 error detected.
    at net.sf.saxon.PreparedStylesheet.prepare(PreparedStylesheet.java:153)
    at net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTemplates(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:137)
    at net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTransformer(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:88)
    at org.mule.module.xml.transformer.XsltTransformer$PooledXsltTransformerFactory.makeObject(XsltTransformer.java:363)
    at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.addObject(GenericObjectPool.java:1615)
    at org.mule.module.xml.transformer.XsltTransformer.initialise(XsltTransformer.java:138)
    ... 52 more
```

This is my .xslt file :

```
<?xml version='1.0' ?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">

 <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes"  indent="yes" />

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()"> 
        <xsl:copy copy-namespaces="yes">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy> 
   </xsl:template>


      <xsl:template match="wsdl:operation[@name = 'GetCityWeatherByZIP']" />  
      <xsl:template match="wsdl:message[@name = 'GetCityWeatherByZIPSoapIn']" /> 
      <xsl:template match="wsdl:message[@name = 'GetCityWeatherByZIPSoapOut']" /> 

      <xsl:template match="wsdl:message[@name = 'GetCityWeatherByZIPHttpGetIn']" /> 
      <xsl:template match="wsdl:message[@name = 'GetCityWeatherByZIPHttpGetOut']" /> 

      <xsl:template match="wsdl:message[@name = 'GetCityWeatherByZIPHttpPostIn']" /> 
      <xsl:template match="wsdl:message[@name = 'GetCityWeatherByZIPHttpPostOut']" /> 

      <xsl:template match="s:element[@name = 'GetCityWeatherByZIP']" /> 


 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: What's the error you're getting?  And did my answer to your last question do what you needed?

Comment: your solution for Delete elements attribute-values in XML (WSDL) file? was good and I could got answer,Thanks. I could remove some of my wsdl:operation + wsdl:message in my WSDL. Now I want to remove some of s:element that there are in my WSDL

Comment: I published out my WSDL file by Mule Studio, and on it I have a .xslt files for WSDL configuration. Now I want to s:element from my WSDL and again publish out it

Comment: My error: Exception in thread "main" org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentInitException: TransformerConfigurationException: Failed to compile stylesheet. 1 error detected.
 at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.init(DefaultMuleApplication.java:220)
 at org.mule.module.launcher.application.ApplicationWrapper.init(ApplicationWrapper.java:64)
 at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultMuleDeployer.deploy(DefaultMuleDeployer.java:46)

Comment: My error is too long, and I can't copy all of them

Comment: Could you add the error to your question text?

Comment: I pasted all of my errors that I saw in my mule-console

Comment: Wow, that really is a lot of errors.  Could you show us the full XSLT you have so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JLRishe has made a good guess as to what is wrong with your stylesheet, but it should not have been necessary to guess. You've shown us the stack trace, which reveals that the XSLT processor reported compile time errors, but you haven't shown us those errors, which probably means you aren't seeing them. By default they will go to the standard error output, and if you're compiling from a Java application, you need to make sure that you direct the diagnostics to somewhere where you can see them. Fixing the current coding error in the stylesheet, without fixing the problem of running the compiler in such a way that you see diagnostics in future, isn't going to get you much further.

You could of course try to develop your stylesheets in an IDE that would detect such errors before you deploy the code. But even then, you should invest in creating a robust logging framework where you are able to find error messages.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the `s:` namespace, you have to declare it in your XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
    xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
```

That's most likely the cause of your issue.

Comment: Thanks, I could got answer :)